# How to add member to conversation/channel using twilio-conversation in react-native?

Tags: react-native, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-conversations

How to add member to conversation/channel using twilio-conversation in react-native  ?

React Native JavaScript SDK.

**conversation.add(chatUserId)**

add() not working, giving **Bad Request** error

Comment: Can you share more info? Are you using the JavaScript SDK? What have you tried? Care to share some examples or what is not working?

Please check out [how do I ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JavaScript SDK as recommended for React Native:

[Add a user to a conversation](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/2.1.0/docs/classes/Conversation.html#add)

So basically

```
conversation.add(<identity>)
```

Comment: thanks for you response. I am doing the same but it is throwing Error: Bad Request

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: I did same, conversation.add(chatUserId) but add() not working, giving Bad Request error.

Comment: As far as I know there should be a more detailed error-message and error-code. Please check [JavaScript Error Handling](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/error-handling-diagnostics#javascript-error-handling).